# Formview hyperlink not clickable in Bootstrap mobile version

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I'm having a problem. I've got 3 formviews in Bootstrap elements, making them responsive. They work just fine on the PC resolutions, but once I make the window smaller, it starts not working properly. I can click the LAST formview just fine, but the 2 other formviews aren't clickable anymore. I can't click the update, delete or new buttons or anything, I don't understand it.

```
<section class="col-md-12 content">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1>Pakker</h1>
        <asp:FormView ID="fv_packages" runat="server" DataSourceID="sds_packages" DataKeyNames="ID" AllowPaging="true">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <div class="input-container">
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Heading") %>' runat="server" ID="HeadingTextBox" CssClass="heading-box" /><br />
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Text") %>' runat="server" ID="TextTextBox" CssClass="text-box" TextMode="MultiLine" /><br />
                </div>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Opdater" CommandName="Update" ID="UpdateButton" CausesValidation="True" />&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Annuller" CommandName="Cancel" ID="UpdateCancelButton" CausesValidation="False" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <div class="input-container">
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Heading") %>' runat="server" ID="HeadingTextBox" CssClass="heading-box" /><br />
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Text") %>' runat="server" ID="TextTextBox" CssClass="text-box" TextMode="MultiLine" /><br />
                </div>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Indsæt" CommandName="Insert" ID="InsertButton" CausesValidation="True" />&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Annuller" CommandName="Cancel" ID="InsertCancelButton" CausesValidation="False" />
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <h3>
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("Heading") %>' runat="server" ID="HeadingLabel" /><br />
                </h3>
                <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("Text") %>' runat="server" ID="TextLabel" /><br />
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Rediger" CommandName="Edit" ID="EditButton" CausesValidation="False" />&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Slet" CommandName="Delete" ID="DeleteButton" CausesValidation="False" />&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Ny" CommandName="New" ID="NewButton" CausesValidation="False" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <PagerTemplate>

                <asp:LinkButton ID="lb_previous" Text="Forrige" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Prev" runat="server" />
                |
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lb_next" Text="Næste" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Next" runat="server" />

            </PagerTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="sds_packages" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:Student10332ConnectionString %>' DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [GFP_Packages] WHERE [ID] = @ID" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [GFP_Packages] ([Heading], [Text]) VALUES (@Heading, @Text)" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [GFP_Packages]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [GFP_Packages] SET [Heading] = @Heading, [Text] = @Text WHERE [ID] = @ID">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32"></asp:Parameter>
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Heading" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Text" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
            </InsertParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Heading" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Text" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32"></asp:Parameter>
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1>Hvorfor os?</h1>
        <asp:FormView ID="fv_whyus" runat="server" DataSourceID="sds_whyus" DataKeyNames="ID" AllowPaging="true">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <div class="input-container">
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Heading") %>' runat="server" ID="HeadingTextBox" CssClass="heading-box" /><br />
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Text") %>' runat="server" ID="TextTextBox" CssClass="text-box" TextMode="MultiLine" /><br />
                </div>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Opdater" CommandName="Update" ID="UpdateButton" CausesValidation="True" />&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Annuller" CommandName="Cancel" ID="UpdateCancelButton" CausesValidation="False" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <div class="input-container">
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Heading") %>' runat="server" ID="HeadingTextBox" CssClass="heading-box" /><br />
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Text") %>' runat="server" ID="TextTextBox" CssClass="text-box" TextMode="MultiLine" /><br />
                </div>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Indsæt" CommandName="Insert" ID="InsertButton" CausesValidation="True" />&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Annuller" CommandName="Cancel" ID="InsertCancelButton" CausesValidation="False" />
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <h3>
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("Heading") %>' runat="server" ID="HeadingLabel" /><br />
                </h3>
                <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("Text") %>' runat="server" ID="TextLabel" /><br />
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Rediger" CommandName="Edit" ID="EditButton" CausesValidation="False" />&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Slet" CommandName="Delete" ID="DeleteButton" CausesValidation="False" />&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Ny" CommandName="New" ID="NewButton" CausesValidation="False" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <PagerTemplate>

                <asp:LinkButton ID="lb_previous" Text="Forrige" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Prev" runat="server" />
                |
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lb_next" Text="Næste" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Next" runat="server" />

            </PagerTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="sds_whyus" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:Student10332ConnectionString %>' DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [GFP_WhyUs] WHERE [ID] = @ID" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [GFP_WhyUs] ([Heading], [Text]) VALUES (@Heading, @Text)" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [GFP_WhyUs]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [GFP_WhyUs] SET [Heading] = @Heading, [Text] = @Text WHERE [ID] = @ID">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32"></asp:Parameter>
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Heading" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Text" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
            </InsertParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Heading" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Text" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32"></asp:Parameter>
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1>Om os</h1>
        <asp:FormView ID="fv_about" runat="server" DataSourceID="sds_about" DataKeyNames="ID" AllowPaging="true">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <div class="input-container">
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Heading") %>' runat="server" ID="HeadingTextBox" CssClass="heading-box" /><br />
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Text") %>' runat="server" ID="TextTextBox" CssClass="text-box" TextMode="MultiLine" /><br />
                </div>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Opdater" CommandName="Update" ID="UpdateButton" CausesValidation="True" />&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Annuller" CommandName="Cancel" ID="UpdateCancelButton" CausesValidation="False" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <div class="input-container">
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Heading") %>' runat="server" ID="HeadingTextBox" CssClass="heading-box" /><br />
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Text") %>' runat="server" ID="TextTextBox" CssClass="text-box" TextMode="MultiLine" /><br />
                </div>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Indsæt" CommandName="Insert" ID="InsertButton" CausesValidation="True" />&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Annuller" CommandName="Cancel" ID="InsertCancelButton" CausesValidation="False" />
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <h3>
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("Heading") %>' runat="server" ID="HeadingLabel" /><br />
                </h3>
                <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("Text") %>' runat="server" ID="TextLabel" /><br />
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Rediger" CommandName="Edit" ID="EditButton" CausesValidation="False" />&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Slet" CommandName="Delete" ID="DeleteButton" CausesValidation="False" />&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Ny" CommandName="New" ID="NewButton" CausesValidation="False" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <PagerTemplate>

                <asp:LinkButton ID="lb_previous" Text="Forrige" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Prev" runat="server" />
                |
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lb_next" Text="Næste" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Next" runat="server" />

            </PagerTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="sds_about" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:Student10332ConnectionString %>' DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [GFP_About] WHERE [ID] = @ID" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [GFP_About] ([Heading], [Text]) VALUES (@Heading, @Text)" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [GFP_About]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [GFP_About] SET [Heading] = @Heading, [Text] = @Text WHERE [ID] = @ID">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32"></asp:Parameter>
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Heading" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Text" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
            </InsertParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Heading" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Text" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32"></asp:Parameter>
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
</section>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which browser(s)/version(s) have you been using? Does this behavior change under different browsers?

Comment: Hello, I've tried in Google Chrome, Internet Explorer and Mozilla Firefox, it does the same thing in every browser. All three browsers I tested it in were the latest versions as well.

Comment: I think you need to put the `col-md-6` within a `row`.

Comment: Within a row? I'm not sure what you mean?